# Apache mod_rewrite: only if no page requested or index.php WITHOUT query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can you use mod_rewrite to rewrite a URL if the following simple requests are made

```
/
/index.php
```

But not for a request with a query string

```
/?query=vars    
/index.php?query=vars
```

I have tried the following

```
DirectoryIndex pages.php?id=1 index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /pages.php?id=1
```

I'm looking for a solution where `mysite.com` and `mysite.com/index.php` would display as written but actually request `mysite.com/pages.php?id=1`

But where `mysite.com/index.php?query=vars` is unaffected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a condition to check for query string:

DirectoryIndex pages.php?id=1 index.php

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ pages.php?id=1 [L,NC]
```

1. `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` will make sure to fire this rule only when query string is empty.
2. `^(index\.php)?$` will make this rule fire for `/index.php` and `/` (landing page).